# Assigning a value to variable inside test condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it acceptable to assign a value to a variable inside the test condition:

```
var word;
while (word = words.pop()) {
// other code
}
```

instead of after the condition is evaluated as part of the execution of the statement:

```
var word;
while (words.pop()) {
  word = words.pop();
  // other code
}
```

Which is better?

Comment: Are you sure they do the same thing? Pop is destructive, so I suspect the second one doesn't do what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. I think the example that Daniel Tran posted was closer to what I wished I wrote as the second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't use assignment in condition to advoid confusion between a logic assert and assignment. = can be misunderstood to ==
Your second code won't work the same because it pop twice. In this case should write like this:

```
while (words.length > 0) {
  let word = word.pop();
  // other code 
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `let` unless it is actually needed. Other than that I think this answer is most likely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Daniel, your comment that the assignment operator will be mistaken as an equality operator is exactly what happened. I used JSHint on the first option and it said it expected an equality operator. While I know JSHint can be customized and some of its suggestions are a matter of taste, this definitely caused an issue and made me wonder what the drawbacks might be.

Answer (score 0):

In the second method if you have an array of four element ("ele1","ele2","ele3","ele4") then on the while condition it will pop ele1 then will assign ele2 to your variable then again in the condition will pop ele3 and assign ele4 to your variable, 
the first method id the better

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign a variable within the condition.

In your example, `word` would still be available within the scope block of the conditional evaluation.

```
while (word = words.pop()) {
    console.log(word);
}
```

That said, a test condition should do just that: test a condition.

It doesn't make your code easier to read if you make that a habit.

Comment: Thank you Cent, this was what I wanted to know, if its a bad habit. I will definitely avoid this as I can see how it does not make the code easier to read. Thank you.